# x64 C++/CLI assemblies still reference to x86 .NET libraries

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, 32bit-64bit

My development environment is Visual Studio 2010.
I'm using managed code in my C++ project, compiling with `/CLI` flag and adding `/FU` with .NET DLLs.

When I'm compiling with 32-bit target machine everything goes right, but when compiling to 64-bit, it seems that the compiler still uses the x86 .NET DLLs.

Additionally, the relative path in **Project Properties -> Common Properties -> Framework and References -> (System) Assembly reference properties -> Relative Path** (uneditable) is pointing to an x86 file.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely normal and **not** a problem.  Reference assemblies are only used by the compiler to retrieve metadata, the declarations of the types in the assembly.  The equivalent of .h files in native C++.  Those declarations do *not* depend on the target architecture.

Architecture dependency is resolved at runtime.  For .NET Framework assemblies that contain native code (mscorlib.dll, System.Data.dll, PresentationFramework.dll), the correct assembly is retrieved from a different GAC subdirectory.  The GAC_32 subdirectory contains assemblies with 32-bit native code, GAC_64 for 64-bit, GAC_MSIL has the assemblies that contain pure IL and therefore have no architecture dependency.